# How to extract output of specific columns from groupby on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, lambda

*Need to extract output of groupBy pandas dataframe into expected output described below and write to a file:*

***Input file testdata.txt:***

```
id, distance

1,0.5
1,1.2
1,0.2   <------------this row should be selected
1,1.5
2,2.5
2,0.5   <------------this row should be selected
2,1.0
2,3.0
```

***Expected output:***
*Find row with shortest distance for each id*

```
1 0.2
2 0.5
```

***Actual Output looks as follows: Need to process this output to get expected output described above:***

```
_1          
1  2  1  0.2
2  5  2  0.5


**My Python Script:**

lines = sc.textFile("file:///data/testdata.txt")
#RDD to Spark DataFrame
sparkDF = lines.map(lambda x: str(x)).map(lambda w: w.split(',')).toDF()

#Spark DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame
pdsDF = sparkDF.toPandas()

#print dataframe schema
print (pdsDF)

StoreIdGroups = pdsDF.groupby(by=['_1'])
result = StoreIdGroups.apply(lambda g: g[g['_2'] == g['_2'].min()])
print(result)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using spark only to read the file? I don't see how the pandas dataframe look like but for a dataframe with id and distance columns you can do `df.groupby('id')['distance'].min()`

Comment: what's the criteria to choose that number? Maybe the minimum?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple case of applying using the `.min()` method of a `DataFrameGroupBy` object:

```
data = [(1,0.5),(1,1.2),(1,0.2),(1,1.5),(2,2.5),(2,0.5),(2,1.0),(2,3.0)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['id', 'distance']
results = df.groupby('id').min()
```

`results` has the data you are looking for. If you want some nice printing, try:

```
for i in results.itertuples():
    print(*tuple(i))
```